# using client_side_validation with Rails4 and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, client-side-validation

I'm having difficulties with client_side_validation and Rails4.
I'm using the 4-0-0-beta gem and I installed everything as said in the documentation. I added the validate => true to the form_for tags inside devise views.

The problem is that when I render the page, the validation javascript seems to get rendered normally, but it won't trigger the validation (or do anything).

Any idea what could be the issue?

Further debugging revealed that javascript is causing the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined (rails.validations.js?body=1:598)
```

Any idea why that could be happening?

Thanks for help!